# How to retrieve session storage values and pass it to radio buttons and checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, json

As the question is asking, can you get the values from the session storage or local storage to radio buttons on html and the same thing for the checkboxes?

My code:

```js
var customername = {"firstname" : getCookie("firstname"), "lastname" : getCookie("lastname")};

var curcustomer1 = {"firstname" : getCookie("firstname"), "lastname" : getCookie("lastname")};

var lastvist = {"date" : dateall} // only display the date and time

    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(customername);
    var myJSON1 = JSON.stringify(lastvist); // has the date when the user last has visited
    
    var myJSON2 = JSON.stringify(curcustomer1);
    
    var myJSON3full = JSON.stringify(custinfo);
    sessionStorage.setItem("custinfo", myJSON3full);
    var objectfull = sessionStorage.getItem("custinfo");
    objfull = JSON.parse(objectfull);

    var object = sessionStorage.getItem("customername");
    obj = JSON.parse(object);
    
    if(object != myJSON) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("customername", myJSON);
        var object = sessionStorage.getItem("customername");
        obj = JSON.parse(object);

        var curcustomer = customername;
        var myJSONcopy = JSON.stringify(curcustomer);
        var object2 = sessionStorage.setItem("curcustomer", myJSONcopy);
        
        var msg5 = "Welcome ";
        document.getElementById("customer").innerHTML = msg5 + " " + "New Customer";
        document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = "";
        
        var radiobtn = document.getElementsByName("type");
        if(radiobtn.value != 8) {
            document.elem.type.value="8";
        }
        
        var radiobtn1 = document.getElementsByName("special");
        if(radiobtn1.value != 0) {
            document.elem.special.value="0";
        }
        
        for (var i = 0; i < extras.length; i++) {
            if (extras[i].checked) {
                extras[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(object == myJSONcopy) {
        radiobtn = document.getElementsByClassName("type").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("type");
        radiobtn1 = document.getElementsByClassName("special").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("special");
        checboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("extras").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("extras");
    }
```

```html
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="8" checked>Small $8.00
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="10">Medium $10.00
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="15">Large $15.00
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="18">Extra Large $18.00
      <br>
      <br>
    </td>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. With `sessionStorage.variable` and `localStorage.getItem("item")` respectively.

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Or with `sessionStorage.getItem("item")` as well.

Comment: @Obsidian Age I tried this and it is erroring on me. checboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("extras").value = sessionStorage.getItem("extras");

Comment: What's the error? Give us the complete scenario.

Comment: Yep :) It's interesting that it doesn't work the other way though; you can use `sessionStorage.variable` to both get and set the variable, but you have to use `localStorage.setItem('ls', variable);` :)

Comment: @Scott Marcus my bad. It's not erroring on me, but it is giving a null value instead.

Comment: Will you please edit your question and show us the code you are working with?  That is the proper way to ask a question here. If you are getting `null`, then you probably haven't set a value into `sessionStorage` yet.

Comment: You still haven't shown us **ALL** the relevant code. What is `object` and `myJSONcopy`? Where are you *SETTING* values into `sessionStorage`?

Comment: It's pretty messy tho.

Comment: You **still** aren't showing all the relevant code. What is `customername`, `lastvisit`, `customerinfo`? These are the values that you are trying to set into storage. If we can reproduce your problem, we can't help you.

Comment: I appreciate the help tho.

Comment: Where is the `getCookie()` function? And, where in the file is all this JavaScript? Come on man - show us what you are working with so we can replicate your issue.

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to add the item to multiple buttons that share the same className then you will have to do something like this:
    
    `var list = document.getElementsByClassName('type');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; n < list.length; ++i) {
         list[i].value= sessionStorage.getItem('events')
    };`

But if it's just one button then I will suggest you use `getElementById` 
like this 
`document.getElementById('Id').value = sessionStorage("events");`

Comment: How will that extract data from `sessionStorage`?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` will return a `nodeList` hence the need for the loop. it will still have access to the `sessionStorage` in the loop.

Comment: My comment was related to your original answer, not this one.